# Fluid ignores obstacle

Tags: fluid-simulation

Hello I am trying to make something like this https://www.reddit.com/r/Simulated/comments/8rt6wx/frosting_a_cake/
(I know this uses flip fluids addon, I am trying to recreate something similar with blender fluid)
This is my problem. 
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Fluid just ignores my cake. Can anyone help me please?
[download blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l6JAN_noAgSJFvsAzx46lLd3bUuC8lkq/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3):

You have to activate the fluid modifier for your cake in the physics panel and set the type to "obstacle". Then you can choose if using the shell (surface), the volume of your obstacle, or both.

For your task I suggest to use shell volume initialization.

If nothing happen you probably have inverted normals. Try recalculate them.

Hope it helped you!

Cheers!

Comment: its not working. fluid just ignores the cake for few seconds.